# #pragma GCC unroll with compile-time argument

Tags: g++, pragma, loop-unrolling

Is there a way to unroll a loop in GCC based on compile-time (e.g., template) parameter?

The following does not compile, unless I replace `unroll(N)` with a concrete integer like `unroll(8)`

```
template<int N>
void fun ()
{
    #pragma GCC unroll(N)
    for (...)
         // body
}
```